# C++ When member copy constructors are called

Tags: c++

Given the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


class Entity {
public:
    Entity(const int x, const int y) :
        x(x), y(y)
    {
        this->entities.push_back(*this);
    }

    int x, y;
    std::vector<Entity> entities;
};


int main() {

    auto p = Entity(10, 20);

    std::cout << p.entities.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << p.x << ' ' << p.y << "\n\n";

    std::cout << p.entities[0].entities.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << p.entities[0].x << ' ' << p.entities[0].y << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

When entities.push_back is called, the Entity should be copied to the vector. When copied all members should have their copy constuctors called in the following order: (x, y, entities). The problem is in the entities constructor, the "std::vector" constructor should call the "Entity" constructor that will call the "std::vector" constructor again, resulting in a infinite loop.

But according to the output:

```
1
10 20

0
10 20
```

The "std::vector" copy constructor is not called.

Where is my error? I'm forgetting some implementation detail?

Comment: How do you know the copy constructor is not called?

Comment: you copy empty vector, then increase size of the *"parent"*

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: default copy constructor...

Comment: Oh I see, they are asking why the copy's vector always appears to be empty..

Comment: Consider carefully what the Entity copy constructor does in this situation.  Try coding up the copy constructor yourself.

Answer (score 4):

> the "std::vector" constructor should call the "Entity" constructor that will call the "std::vector" constructor again, resulting in a infinite loop

Nope.

The `std::vector<Entity>` **copy** constructor will call the `Entity` **copy** constructor.

The `Entity` **copy constructor** copies the member vector as it currently exists (empty).  It does not run the code in the two-element `Entity` constructor that `push_back` something to the vector.

Answer (score 2):

You're copying yourself in a constructor, which is generally a bad practice since the object is not yet fully constructed. In this case, the vector is still empty when you call `push_back`.